# Assign a license bound perm set to a user with Salesforce license

Tags: permission-sets, userlicense

I have a user who is assigned a Salesforce user license. I am not able to assign him a permission set that is bound to a Salesforce Platform license. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Try a logical clone (you'll need the IDE to do this) of the PermissionSet and remove the licensetype field. Then you can assign to a normal Salesforce user